# Subscribing to Created Observable calling Api Again

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have an Api that returns an array of objects and converts it into an object for [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) like so

```
    getRoles(): Observable<Array<Select2OptionData>> {
    return this.authHttp.get(`${this.usersUrl}/GetRoles`)
        .map(function (response) {
            var result = response.json();

            var temp = [];
            result.forEach(function (dept) {
                var d = {
                    'id': '0',
                    'text': dept.name,
                    'children': []
                };

                dept.roles.forEach(function (role) {
                    var r = {
                        'id': role.id.toString(),
                        'text': role.name
                    };
                    d.children.push(r);
                }, this);
                temp.push(d);
            }, this);
            return temp;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The return of this is an Array of Select2OptionData that has children

```
export interface Select2OptionData {
id: string;
text: string;
children?: Array<Select2OptionData>;
additional?: any;
}
```

In order to load the Dropdown, I have to pass it the observable like so

```
getRoles(): void {
  this.roleDepartments =  this.userService
        .getRoles();
}

<select2 class="form-control" [data]="roleDepartments | async"  (valueChanged)="changed($event)" [width]="300"></select2>
```

This works as expected and the dropdown is populated with data when it is loaded. I now want to be able to capture the value that is selected on change and that is supported. The issue is I need to iterate over the values of "roleDepartments" and get the whole object for the selected value. Since the object is Observable, I cannot iterate over it. I have tried subscribing to it, assigning the result into a variable and iterating over that. When I try that, the Api that populates the Observable is called again. Am I going about doing this the best way? If not, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the reason that subscribing to the observable again is that it is what is known as a "cold observable". That means that every new subscriber will get a new copy of the observable, and kick off any work done to create that observable. In the case of `Http`, it will make a new request.

So we need a way to turn it from a "cold" observable into one that won't resubmit the request when we subscribe, but rather return the most recent result immediately instead. We can do that by adding on the `.publishReplay(1)` operator followed by the `.refCount()` operator so that the first subscriber kicks off the request, and the last unsubscriber unsubscribes from the observable in question.

This way, in the `change()` method, you can do:

```
this.roleDepartments.take(1).subscribe(roles => {
    let option: Select2OptionData;
    roles.forEach(role => {
        if (role.id === selectedId) {
             option = role;
        }
    });
});
```

That will get only the replayed value (the most recent value emitted by the original observable) and then unsubscribe thanks to the `.take(1)`.

This approach is less prone to leaks, I believe, because there is no chance of leaving a dangling subscription to the observable that you forget to unsubscribe from. This is because using the `async` pipe is safe - Angular takes care of subscribing and unsubscribing correctly for you, and the other subscription in the `change()` method only happens after the initial load of data and then immediately automatically unsubscribes.

### A simpler approach

A simpler solution (that is easier to screw up and cause leaks) is to have your component subscribe to the observable once in the `ngOnInit()` hook, store the array of roles away as well as the subscription object, and then in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook, unsubscribe. Finally, in the template, you don't need to use the `async` pipe at all.

It is easier to cause leaks because if you (or a future developer) forget to unsubscribe, you risk introducing a memory leak by preventing your controller instance from being cleaned up.

But if you are happy to take that risk, here is what it would look like:

```
 @Component({
      // ...
 })
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      private rolesSubscription: Subscription;
      private roleDepartments: Select2OptionData[];

      constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
          this.rolesSubscription = this.userService.getRoles()
                                       .subscribe(roles => this.roleDepartments = roles);
      }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
          this.rolesSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      change(selectedId: string) {
          // find correct role from this.roles and do something with it
      }
}
```

and then in your template, change it slightly to:

```
<select2 class="form-control" [data]="roleDepartments" 
         (valueChanged)="changed($event)" [width]="300">
</select2>
```